# Deploy ddl as declarative xml states

Tags: xml, oracle, deployment, ddl

I'm working with Oracle database and as many of you I have the same problem deploying DDL statements as they are not declarative.

I'm looking for a tool to export table structures/sequences/constraints/indexes from one instance as an XML file and import it to the another instance. Moreover I would like that import to be intelligent, I mean if the difference between importing table and existing one is one new column added in schema, "alter table add column" is executed. If the column type is changed then "alter table modify" is executed, missing tables/constraints/indexes are created and so on.

This way I can version the database state in the declarative manner and store such XMLs in the version control system.

For now I'm not looking for the lookup tables content, only structures.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason that you need the interim XML file?  As opposed to, say, a SQL script?  Just about any PL/SQL IDE (TOAD, SQL Developer, etc.) has the ability to connect to two different databases and generate the DDL required to make one look like the other by generating appropriate DDL statements.  The developers that implement the original change, though, would normally be checking in their original scripts in to source control rather than reverse engineering every change since that tends to be clearer about what you are specifying and what you are letting default.

Comment: Yes, @JustinCave, we've tried this technique but it still leads to saving DDL change scripts to source control. What I want is to save states and an algorithm to move the instance from one state to another just like we store package states. And also I would like to include that XML into my patch to be processed on the production instance. I really would like to operate tables as packages.

Answer (score 0):

i know of no such thing that currently exists..

your first requirement of having an XML representation of a table is relativley straightforward

```
create table my_table (col1 varchar2(10),col2 number(5,3), col3 DATE);
Table MY_TABLE created.

set pagesize 500
set long 10000
select SYS.dbms_metadata.get_sxml('TABLE','MY_TABLE') from dual;
```

```
SYS.DBMS_METADATA.GET_SXML('TABLE','MY_TABLE')                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <TABLE xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ku" version="1.0">
   <SCHEMA>MI_PAR</SCHEMA>
   <NAME>MY_TABLE</NAME>
   <RELATIONAL_TABLE>
      <COL_LIST>
         <COL_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>COL1</NAME>
            <DATATYPE>VARCHAR2</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>10</LENGTH>
         </COL_LIST_ITEM>
         <COL_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>COL2</NAME>
            <DATATYPE>NUMBER</DATATYPE>
            <PRECISION>5</PRECISION>
            <SCALE>3</SCALE>
         </COL_LIST_ITEM>
         <COL_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>COL3</NAME>
            <DATATYPE>DATE</DATATYPE>
         </COL_LIST_ITEM>
      </COL_LIST>
      <PHYSICAL_PROPERTIES>
         <HEAP_TABLE>
            <SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES>
               <SEGMENT_CREATION_DEFERRED></SEGMENT_CREATION_DEFERRED>
               <PCTFREE>10</PCTFREE>
               <PCTUSED>40</PCTUSED>
               <INITRANS>1</INITRANS>
               <TABLESPACE>USERS</TABLESPACE>
               <LOGGING>Y</LOGGING>
            </SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES>
            <COMPRESS>N</COMPRESS>
         </HEAP_TABLE>
      </PHYSICAL_PROPERTIES>
   </RELATIONAL_TABLE>
</TABLE>
```

as for converting that into a delta that's left as an exercise for the reader.. :p

but seriously.. options would be passing this XML to a script/procedure on the destination database. which would do the compare, generate the delta and eiterh output back to the user or apply directly via `dbms_sql/execute immediate`

sorry if i wasnt more help